# PHPUnit store properties on test class

Tags: php, testing, properties, phpunit

I'm a beginner with PHPUnit.

This is a sample test class that I've created:

```
class NewTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $foo;

    function testFirst ()
    {
        $this->foo = true;
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
    }

    /**
     * @depends testFirst
     */
    function testSecond ()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
    }
}
```

When testSecond is executed, it throws an error saying "`Undefined property NewTest::$foo`".

Why does this happen? Does PHPUnit clear new properties after each test execution? Is there a way to set a property in a test so that it will be accessible in other tests of the same test class?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are setting the foo property inside the `testFirst()` method. PHPUnit will reset the environment between tests/create a new instance of "NewTest" for every test method if they don't have a @depends annotation), so if you want to have `foo` set to `true` you have to recreate that state in the dependent test or use the `setup()` method.

### With `setup()` ([docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/fixtures.html)):

```
class NewTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $foo;
    protected function setup()
    {
        $this->foo = TRUE;
    }
    function testFirst ()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
    }
    /**
     * @depends testFirst
     */
    function testSecond ()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
    }
}
```

### With `@depends` ([docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies)):

```
class NewTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $foo;
    function testFirst ()
    {
        $this->foo = TRUE;
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
        return $this->foo;
    }
    /**
     * @depends testFirst
     */
    function testSecond($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->assertTrue($this->foo);
    }
}
```

All of the above should pass.

***EDIT*** *had to remove the @backupGlobals solution. It was plain wrong.*

Comment: Note that this can cause a `PHP Fatal error` in recent PHPUnit versions (I don't know exactly since what exact version). You cannot declare `protected function setup()` in that way but you need `protected function setup(): void`. Also, `setup()` is called before every test. So probably the user may need `public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void` that is called only once and at the beginning, and it's not called all the times before every test. https://docs.phpunit.de/en/7.5/fixtures.html?highlight=setup()#variations
Also, the link needs an update since it's just the homepage of PHPUnit

Answer (score 4):

- You can use the [@depends annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)
- You can initialize something in the [setUp()](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) method

Generally, you want to avoid that one test influences another test. This makes sure the test is clean and always works, instead of in some edge-case which test1 creates.